# Pass data in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to pass data from Master view controller to Detail view controller according to the picture below. I am using *protocols and Delegates* to pass data. There is no problem to pass data from A to B. It happens when I try to pass data from A to C.

[image]

But the app is returning the error:

> 014-07-05 01:03:00.043 PassingDataBack[2216:70b] -[UIViewController
>   didSelectData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e3d2d0
>   2014-07-05 01:03:00.047 PassingDataBack[2216:70b] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIViewController didSelectData:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x8e3d2d0'

I believe the problem is in the AppDelegate file that i wrote:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    splitViewController.delegate = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] topViewController];
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = (MasterViewController *)[[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController];
    masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Could you help to find the solution?